# Bad smell in down stairs bathroom

Tags: plumbing

Every once in a while this horrible smell cones out of the bathroom.  Smells like urine.  It will be there for a few days to a week then goes away but it is overwhelming when it's there . The bathroom is clean. And it comes and goes. What could it be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What could be causing a urine smell in our bathrooms?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/what-could-be-causing-a-urine-smell-in-our-bathrooms)

Comment: I don't think that dupe provides the mostly likely answer, which is simply a dry trap.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use that bathroom often? If the sink goes without use for an extended period of time you might get a sewer gas smell. The p-trap in the sink drain can dry out causing sewer gas to leak through the drain. The next time it happens run water in the sink and if you have a tub or shower then there too. See if it helps.